# Positioning div at the bottom

Tags: html, position, positioning

Okay, so my question is this. How can I position a child element being another div inside a main div without using margin-top? Please check my screenshot to understand my question a little better.

My main div is 177px by 177px. My child div is 100px by 25px I need at the bottom of the main div floating right with about 20px margin-bottom.

Thanks,
Richard.[image]

Comment: Could you please show us the code you currently have? It would give us the ability to better help you.

Comment: Hi Richard i advice please post your HTML and CSS code, so people know where is goes wrong? :D

Comment: Perhaps this CSS positioning tutorial might help? http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use absolute postitioning.  Position your main div to relative and then your inner div to absolute like the following:

```
.main-div {
  position: relative;
  height: 177px;
  width: 177px;
}
.inner-div {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

Comment: That would make the `.inner-div` always 20px from the bottom of the screen, and not the bottom of the div. Also, you have a typo for the first `position:`.

Comment: Your welcome I fixed the typo and position fixed will position it to the bottom of the screen position absolute will position the item in an absolute position inside of the next relative positioned item.  So if you position an element to relative and then position an item absolute inside of the relative item the absolute positioned item will be always in the same spot relative to the item that you positioned relative if that makes sense